# Why in certain airports the windows are blocked while others not?

Tags: airport, security

In certain airports, like the T1 of MMMX the windows are blocked or semi-blocked

[image: blocked window]

while in others are not (MMGL)

[image: unblocked window]

I understand this could be done to avoid debris hit the windows, but then why?

Comment: Are they not simply sun shades?

Comment: @TobySpeight Its too wide and heavy to be, but I didn't think this way.

Comment: I don't see that this has much to do with aviation. Airport windows are presumably like windows in any other large building, so the considerations about building codes, sunlight, cleaning, maintenance etc. would be the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Keep the sun out if facing south or west, help keep the temperature down.

Comment: Or North, if in the Southern hemisphere. :) Or pretty much any direction in the tropics.